# Не работает перелистывание в kde

Tags: kde

Активировал в эффектах перелистывание по alt-tab, но оно не работает, почему? Что сделать чтоб работало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметры системы -> Рабочая среда -> Диспетчер окон -> Переключение окон -> Визуализация.
В комбике выбрать перелистывание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]